# YouTube thumbnails - options for adjusting interface widgets and behaviour when clicked?

Tags: 7, entities, theming, files

I wish to add YouTube videos to my site as links - I want to use a thumbnail of the video. I'm not concerned with which thumbnail used (as discussed here: How to control preview image in Youtube)

What I am concerned with is how the play etc. buttons look on a thumbnail (i.e. everything reduced in size from how it would appear in YouTube).

What options do YouTube themselves offer? And what about 3rd-party solutions?

Facebook for example does this quite well - the thumbnail is not too cluttered and will expand when clicked onto to a usable size to view the video at a reasonable size on the same page (an example of my requirement for behaviour when clicked).

Any examples of such customisations on Drupal sites, please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: @Chapabu Drupal 7 - more specifically using a Drupal Gardens site export as starting point because it has the Acquia Media module setup to manage galleries out-of-the-box. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module, it's pretty new but under active development. It will just show the thumbnail and when you click it load the video player page.

However, they are working on a lightbox integration (video plays in a popup modal) and you might want to suggest the "Facebook player functionality" as a new feature to them.

Comment: Can I use it with Drupal 7 Views 3?

Comment: yes. Btw, if the thumbnail doesn't turn into a link just rewrite it to "node/[nid]".

Comment: A bit more detail about which options to choose in Views would be welcome too.

Comment: checkout http://drupal.org/node/1349834 once you have it installed and configured